# Zabbix run action(remote command) manualy

Tags: zabbix

Zabbix version: 2.0

Is there any way to run action(remote command) manualy from web interface? I didn't find any

Comment: Such a feature immediately strikes me across the face with ***BIG GAPING SECURITY HOLE***...

Comment: Why? Zabbiox supports remote commands, if agent is configured respectively. I just want to run it manualy, not on a trigger change.

Comment: Exposing unrestricted remote commands in general is ***always*** a security hole (be it Zabbix, Nagios, or SNMP). Doing it via a web interface is doubly bad.

Comment: Only administrator should have access to web interface. Yes, Zabbix is central place for administrative access, compromising it can lead to loss of all infrastructure. And so are Bacula, Puppet, Active Directory, ... It's not a security hole, it's desing particularity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zabbix supports user-defined scripts, here it is: http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/ru/2.0/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/administration/scripts